# Python aiohttp been receiving SSL transport errors

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

We have an application running that relies heavily on asyncio.
It sends hundreds of get requests per minute to mostly the same host, but with different urls.
Since about 3 weeks, we observe the following issues:

1. The process gets stuck, often for up to (exactly) 2400 seconds.
2. We observe the following error in the logging:

   2018-12-07T23:37:33Z ERROR base_events.py: Fatal error on SSL transport protocol: 
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 638, in _process_write_backlog ssldata, offset = self._sslpipe.feed_appdata(data, offset)

Python version: 3.6.3
aiohttp version: 3.4.4

**Question 1:** Does anyone know what is going on here? And how can we get rid of those nasty periods of the process getting stuck ... ? (Or how to debug?)

**Question 2:** Can this be related?: https://bugs.python.org/issue29406

Comment: Please check the latest Python: 3.7.1 or at least 3.6.6
Python 3.6.6 has several SSL related bug fixes that landed after 3.6.3

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Thank you for your comment. The problem started appearing about 3 weeks ago, so I was hoping for some other hints than _update your software_ ... have any further ideas maybe  ... ?

Comment: @YtsendeBoer a word of advice: it's very hard to locate problem if it can't be reproduced. Log url and request params when you face the error. It'll allow you, for example, to see if it's aiohttp/asyncio related at all and to try out different solutions.

Comment: This reminds me more of https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2546 than the referenced bpo. By all means try newest versions (py3.7.1, py3.8-dev / aiohttp git).

Comment: It might also help to get a stack trace when process is stuck.

Comment: Got a new comment on reference bpo -- `"use uvloop"`, which I agree with, you shold use `uvloop` when you handle this much traffic.